# How To Get The Value Of Header In CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint-2010

In PowerShell I want to pass the name of a header in a CSV file into another function in the PowerShell script.

How can I retrieve the value-text of a header name into a variable in CSV?

e.g. if I have the following CSV data:

```
ID Name     Country
-- ----     -------
1  John     United States
2  Beatrice Germany
3  Jouni    Finland
4  Marcel   France
```

In the above example how can I retrieve the Country column value text as "Country" text into a variable in my script?

(Note: I am familiar with the notation $_.Country to retrieve the value of, for example, "Germany" from a row by importing the CSV in Powershell)

My specific issue is that currently I have the following function in my script:

```
function GetItemIdFromTitle([string]$LookupTitle, [ref]$LookupId)
{   
    $LookupField = $LookupList.Fields["DEPTCATEGORY"]   
    $LookupItem = $LookupList.Items | where {$_['DEPTCATEGORY'] -like "*$LookupTitle*"} 
    $LookupId.Value = $LookupItem.ID
}
```

This currently takes a string value -> $LookupTitle and uses that to find an item in a SharePoint list.  As you can see in the script I am hard-coding in the column name as "DEPTCATEGORY".  This is the column name that will be looked up to in the SharePoint list.

Instead of hard-coding the column name I want to pass in the name of the column for the corresponding $LookupTitle value and replace the hard-coded "DEPTCATEGORY".

I am calling the above function as follows:

```
#GET THE LOOKUP COLUMN ID       
GetItemIdFromTitle $_.DEPTCAT ([ref]$LookupIdValue)
```

( $_.DEPTCAT is the value from the row in the CSV column. )

Can I do something like

```
$myCountryColumnName = $_.Country.Property.Title
```

or

```
$myCategoryColumnName = $_.DEPTCAT.Property.Name
```

to get the column name from the CSV?

Answer (score 30):

Assuming that you have already read in the CSV using `Import-CSV` you can examine the property of the resulting object. Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25764540/3829407) but **maintains column order** in the resulting array

Examining the first row / element

```
$data = import-csv $path
$data[0].psobject.properties.name
```

So the second line will return a string array of the properties.

Comment: This is better than the response by @ojk as it is more efficient and reduces cpu cycles. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

If you have an object in $obj, you could list all the property headers like this:

```
$obj | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
```

This is an array, so you can reference them individually like this:

```
($obj | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name')[0]
```

This would just give you the name of the first property for instance.

Comment: I am looping through the rows in the CSV so I need to get the name of the column for the appropriate value in the row and then pass the column name to a function.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. If you are iterating through the rows and are accessing the values, you need the property name to do that. Could you give me an example with some more detail of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Try the amended answer

Comment: I added a more specific example to my question.

Comment: Ok, so you basically want to lookup the property name from a property value? I'm not really sure if this is possible, and I don't really get why you would need it. In one of your examples: `$myCountryColumnName = $_.Country.Property.Title` the property name in question is Country, but you already have that as you are using it in `$_.Country`, so why can't you just use `$myCountryColumnName = 'Country'`?

Comment: Because I wanted to get it from the name for the column in the CSV.  It would be useful to do this where I don't know what the column names are but still need to import the CSV file.  It would allow me to make the script more generic instead of hard-coding the column names in the script.

Answer (score 7):

To get the column name from the csv, first, put the names of the column headers into an array (this will also allow you to loop through each column, if needed) ...

```
$inFilePath = "C:\path\to\file.csv"
$csvColumnNames = (Get-Content $inFilePath | Select-Object -First 1).Split(",")
```

... , secondly, index into the array by column position (index starts at 0). Given your original example it would be;

```
$myCountryColumnName = $csvColumnNames[2]
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this solution isn't compliant with RFC-4180.  It will break if there is escaped text within the CSV that contains commas.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a general comment than an answer.

I needed to pull the first column header name from CSVs and I started with selecting the NoteProperty fields from Get-Member.  This doesn't work because the order of the NoteProperty column header names might not match the order of the column headers in the CSV file.

futureSPQR's method will work every time because the text won't get reordered on you.  Below is my one-liner version of his method to get the first column header name.

```
((Get-Content filename.csv)[0] -split(','))[0]
```

Comment: This assumes that the `CSV` file will not have the type header that `export-csv` adds by default. If the `CSV` doesn't have that type header, you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = Import-Csv "...csv"

Get-Member -InputObject $f[0] |
  Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"} |
  select-object Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to check if a header name exists in the array, use below code

```
$Array | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty'| where {$_.Name -eq "ColumnName"}
```